# How to rewrite rule based on folder and file type in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying to implement a rewrite rule for a downloads folder so that I can serve files that end with .gif, .jpg, .png, .css, .js or .swf and send users to user.php for every other file.

For example: I should hit this URL :  `www.somewhere.com/downloads/mypic.jpg`, 
but when I try : `www.somewhere.com/downloads/my.pdf` I should be redirected to user.php.

So far, I have :

```
RewriteRule ^*/downloads//!(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /base/user.php?a=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Here are some samples for expected behaviour :

### good

www.somewhere.com/downloads/mypic.jpg

www.somewhere.com/downloads/otherpic.png

www.somewhere.com/downloads/scripts/jquery.js

### bad

www.somewhere.com/downloads/my.pdf > send the request to www.somewhere.com/base/user.php

www.somewhere.com/downloads/readme.txt > send the request to www.somewhere.com/base/user.php

www.somewhere.com/downloads/postman.json > send the request to www.somewhere.com/base/user.php

Comment: Need more clarity. Do you want to skip all `*.pdf` files or just `my.pdf`?

Comment: How do you want to separate the two URLs? What makes the second case different from the fist case? You need to specify some form of logic...

Comment: @anubhava I need to skip all *.pdf or any other file that is not in the (... ).

Comment: Can you add some example URLs in question to tell us which ones of them should be routed to `/base/user.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to redirect, when a request to a forbidden extension exists. This worked for me :

RewriteRule ^*/downloads/(.*.(pdf|txt|json))$ /base/user.php?a=$0 [R=302,L]

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?downloads/([^/]+)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /base/user.php?a=$1 [R=302]
```

The above rule will *redirect* the browser, so change the visible URL. That is what you suggest yourself in your question. In case you want to implement an *internal* rewriting instead you need to alter the flag slightly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?downloads/([^/]+)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /base/user.php?a=$1 [END]
```

This rule will work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess`). Obviously the rewriting modules must be enabled in your http server. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration you need to enable its interpretation first, take a look at the `AllowOverride` directive in the official documentation for that.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

In your modification of the question it becomes clear that what you try to implement actually is the opposite of what you apparently asked before. Here is a modified version of the above rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads/[^/]+\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$
RewriteRule !^/?downloads/([^/]+\.\w+)$ /base/user.php?a=$1 [R=302]
```

---

And another general remark: often it makes more sense to not grant *any* access directly to files in the server side physical file system but to implement a router script instead which controls access to all such files. This allows for more fine grained access control and keeps the physical layout separated from the URL set you define.

Comment: I can still hit the pdf file under downloads. This is actually sending me to user.php if I am hitting an image file.

Comment: @CFNinja Certainly you can, since the rules is explicitly designed _not_ to match such files. Since your question is unclear and your additional comment does not help further I answered best as I could. So maybe it makes sense that you `edit` your question and really try to explain what you actually want. What you mean by "skip" and "hit". Since currently all we can do is _guess_. Oh, and... _please_ do not add additional information in comments, use the `edit` link below your question for that.

Comment: @CFNinja I added a modified rule set which implements a condition. That way the actual rewriting rule will only get applied if the request does _not_ match the pattern with the valid file name extensions.

Comment: I am lost now. I can hit the image files, css, js and the pdf files. I shouldn't be hitting the pdf files at all. Only files allowed are the ones with listed extensions.

Comment: @CFNinja Then most likely your rule set does not get applied at all. Either you did not enable that as I pointed out in the answer or you are using a dynamic configuration file in the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

Have this rule inside `downloads/.htaccess` file (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|png|jpe?g|css|js|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /base/user.php?a=$0 [R=302,L,NC,QSA]
```